# How to split the string using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I had following `string`

```
"name;SR4;Multi-Temp;Models:C-600M;S-600DE;S-600M"
```

From this `string` ,

```
{
  "name": "SR4",
  "type": "Muti-Temp",
  "Models": 
          [
             "C-600M", 
            "S-600DE", 
             "S-600M"
          ]
}
```

I'm stuck in do that , Is that possible to get those values from the above string

`semi-colon` is all over the place and couldn't write a proper regex.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research - [search SO for answers](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript+parse+string+with+semicolons+site%3Astackoverflow.com).  If you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output using the [\[<>\]](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) snippet editor.

Comment: You did not post enough information or any effort. How do you determine that "Trailer" should be ignored or replaced by "name"? Are the words the same in all future strings or is it only the semicolon we can split on? Are all strings after Models, models?

Comment: Try [Named capturing group](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Backreferences)

Comment: I edited the question , Can you please check now

Comment: Can you please answer `Are the words the same in all future strings or is it only the semicolon we can split on? Are all strings after Models, models`

Comment: keys is always same in future (name,models). Values might change (SR4,Multi-Temp)

Comment: So `name:` or `name;` ??? `"name:SR4;Multi-Temp;Models:C-600M;S-600DE;S-600M"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is a match and some splits. A oneliner is likely harder to read

Change `[:;]` to `:` or `;` depending on your string

```js
const string = "name:SR4;Multi-Temp;Models:C-600M;S-600DE;S-600M"

const [match,nameString,modelString] = string.match(/name[:;](.*);Models:(.*)/);
console.log({nameString},{modelString})
const [name,type] = nameString.split(";")
console.log({name},{type})
const models = modelString.split(";")
console.log(models)

const result = {name,type,models}
console.log(result)
```